# .NET reference to cached item (DataTable)

Tags: .net, caching

I'm seeing what seems like strange behaviour when dealing with a DataTable I'm storing in the cache. Although it may be by design.

The scenario is simple. I'm storing the results of a DB query in a DataTable and dropping that into that cache. After doing the DB query or grabbing the results from the cache I need to do some post manipulation on it (such as adding a column or ordering). It seems like the manipulation is happening to the item in the cache. So when I grab the item from the cache it must be grabbing a reference to it?

The code

```
string CacheKey = "SearchData";
DataTable CachedResults = null;
object CachedObject = Cache[CacheKey];
if (CachedObject is DataTable) { CachedResults = (DataTable)CachedObject; }
if (CachedResults == null)
{
  CachedResults = new DataTable();
  // Query the database and fill CachedResults

  if (Cache[CacheKey] == null)
  {
    Cache.Add(CacheKey, CachedResults, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Low, null);
  }

}

CachedResults.Columns.Add("NewColumn");
```

I guess my question is, is CachedResults simply a reference to the cached item? And if I want to avoid that I'd need to do a copy on the DataTable?

Thanks so much,
Maleks

Comment: You've answered your own question correctly. Yes, CacheResults is simply a reference to the cached item, and you do need to make a copy (DataTable.Copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually depends on what the underlying cache provider is. If it is the in-memory provider, then yes: you are manipulating a single reference to an object. This could be very bad, since `DataTable` is not thread-safe - plus you will confuse other code using it.

If, however, you are using something like sql-server as a backend for cache, it will serialize and deserialize.

Personally, my advice is therefore: **only cache immutable data**, or, if you *must* cache mutable data, **don't mutate it** when getting it from cache.

In your specific case, yes: copying the `DataTable` after fetch would avoid the issue.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Out of interest, what would you consider mutable data that is safe to cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a reference to the cached item.  The way I've always managed it is to copy as soon as I retrieve it from the cache so the changes aren't automatically reflected.